# Remove Empty Element using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Initially using the System.Xml.Linq dll version 3.5.0.0 I have removed the Empty Element as given below

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(_fileName);                      
document.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value)).Remove();
document.Save(_fileName, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Now my  System.Xml.Linq dll version is 4.0.0.0 but the above code is not working as I cant see the  Where clause.

Can anyone help me how I can rewrite the code remove the empty element in 4.0.0.0

Comment: Do you have `using System.Xml.Linq;` and `using System.Linq;` in your code file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
        var document = XDocument.Parse(original);
        document.Descendants()
       .Where(a=> a.IsEmpty || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Value))
       .Remove();
```

Also you should have the following namespaces,

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: Sorry as I mentioned in the above Where clause is not there for  System.Xml.Linq dll version is 4.0.0.0.This will not wrok

Comment: i have compiled it using System.Xml.Linq dll version 4.0.0.0

Comment: what is your project version?

Comment: The project version is 4.0

Comment: Error=System.collection.generic.IEnumerable<System.XML.Ling.Element> does not contain definition for where clause

Comment: bro do you have system.linq namespace added?